# Apache configuration to route only example.com and example.com/ but not example.com/something

Tags: apache, apache2, cgi

I am using php and python based pages on my website. I want my root page example.com and example.com/ to be served using python and remaining all the pages by php say (example.com/url).

If I add a scriptalias directive for /, all requests are instead forwarded to python and php is starved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ScriptAliasMatch ^/$ instead of ScriptAlias /